# Get Image from Canvas after drawing shapes in SWT

Tags: canvas, swt

I´m trying to get an `Image` object based on a `Canvas` in SWT, first I´m drawing some random shapes to fill the canvas, then I try to get the image and read the image pixels like this:

```
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            // Draw 100 random shapes
            for(int a=0; a<100; a++) {
                e.gc.setBackground(randomColor());
                e.gc.fillOval(randomPosition(), randomPosition(), randomSize(), randomSize());
            }
                    
            // Create image based on canvas
            Image img = new Image(display, canvas.getBounds());
            GC imageGC = new GC(img);
            canvas.print(imageGC);
            imageGC.dispose();

            ImageData imageData = img.getImageData();

            int width = imageData.width;
            int height = imageData.height;

            // Get pixels
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            imageData.getPixels(0, 0, width * height, pixels, 0);

            // Display RGB values of each pixel
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    int pixelValue = pixels[y * width + x];
                    
                    int red = pixelValue & 0xFF;
                    int blue= (pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    int green = (pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF;

                    System.out.println("Color of pixel (" + x + ", " + y + "): RGB(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But it always displays the following as if the Canvas was empty:

```
Color of pixel (0, 0): RGB(0, 0, 0)
Color of pixel (1, 0): RGB(0, 0, 0)
Color of pixel (2, 0): RGB(0, 0, 0)
Color of pixel (3, 0): RGB(0, 0, 0)
Color of pixel (4, 0): RGB(0, 0, 0)
...
```

Does anyone knows why the Canvas seems to be empty even if I can see the shapes in the screen?

Comment: Probably the painting to the Canvas is not completed until the paint listener returns. Do the `print` separately.

Comment: Testing this on macOS it crashes with a StackOverflowError - doing the `print` in the paint listener is definitely wrong. If I move the print code to a mouse down listener (for example) I get the correct colours.

Comment: You are right, if I move the paint to somewhere else it works, but now I think I have a bug on how ot get the RGB values, I get the correct values for the red and green components but blue is always 0

Comment: I used PaletteData instead of accessing the bits of the pixelValue and now it works fine, if you make this an answer I will mark it as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paint listener should only paint the control. Exactly when the drawing is written to the control is not defined and may vary between platforms. You should assume that it is not done until the code returns from the paint listener.

As an example of the variations in behaviour your code produces a stack overflow on macOS because the paint event is called recursively by the `print` call.

So the `print` and the code to extra the data should be done separately from the paint.